# Generating XSD from external classes as well without import

Tags: java, xml, maven, xsd, jaxb

I am using `com.sun.tools.jxc.maven2:maven-jaxb-schemagen-plugin` to generate an XSD file from various POJO classes in my project. This works fine and creates file `A.xsd`.

One of those files has a reference to an enum from an external package that I do not control and cannot change. That enum doesn't have a namespace or any sort of annotations specified.

Generating works fine but it generates file `A.xsd` for my namespace and a file `schema2.xsd` for the enum, which is then imported in `A.xsd`.

For reasons I will not cover, I can only have 1 XSD file for this so **I need the enum to also be generated to `A.xsd`**.

Here's the `pom.xml` code I use for this:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.sun.tools.jxc.maven2</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jaxb-schemagen-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-jaxb-schemagen-version}</version>
        <inherited>false</inherited>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <destdir>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsds</destdir>
            <srcdir>${basedir}/src/main/java/domain;${basedir}/src/main/java/enums</srcdir>
            <includes>
                <include>*.java</include>
            </includes>
            <verbose>true</verbose>
            <schemas>
                <schema>
                    <namespace>http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema/A</namespace>
                    <file>A.xsd</file>
                </schema>
            </schemas>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

I tried replacing the `<schema>` with this:

```
<schema>
    <namespace>*</namespace>
    <file>A.xsd</file>
</schema>
```

and this:

```
<schema>
    <namespace>http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema</namespace>
    <file>A.xsd</file>
</schema>
```

and this:

```
<schema>
    <namespace>http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema/*</namespace>
    <file>A.xsd</file>
</schema>
```

I tried adding this along with the one specifying `A.xsd`:

```
<schema>
    <namespace>http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema</namespace>
    <file>A.xsd</file>
</schema>
```

None of the above worked.

How can I achieve the required behavior?